# Error While Saving the Class

Tags: apex, trigger, class, salesforcedx

Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: lstOppotunityToUpdate at line 34 column 17

Code:

```
public class QuoteLineItemTriggerHandler
{
    public static void syncQuotes(List<QuoteLineItem>newLineItems)
    {
        // get quote ids we need to query for
        Set<Id> quoteIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (QuoteLineItem qli : newLineItems)
        {
            if (qli.QuoteId != null)
            {
                quoteIds.add(qli.QuoteId);
            }
        }

        // Linking quote line item with Opportunity Line Items
        Map<ID,ID> mapQuoteLineItemSortOrder= returnDefaultLinking(quoteIds);

        //Fetch opportunity line item for sync
        Map<ID,OpportunityLineItem> mapOppLineItems=new Map<ID,OpportunityLineItem>();
        for(OpportunityLineItem oli:[select id, Finalization__c from OpportunityLineItem where Opportunity.SyncedQuoteId in :quoteIds])
        {
            mapOppLineItems.put(oli.id,oli);
        }

        List<id> LineItemlstOppotunityToUpdate = new List<id>();
        for (QuoteLineItem qli : newLineItems) 
        {
            OpportunityLineItem oli = mapOppLineItems.get(mapQuoteLineItemSortOrder.get(qli.Id));
            if (oli != null ) 
            {
                oli.Finalization__c=qli.Finalization__c;
                //update more fields....

                lstOppotunityToUpdate.add(oli);
            }
        }
        update lstOppotunityToUpdate;
    }
    private static Map<ID,ID> returnDefaultLinking(Set<id> poIds)
    {
        Map<ID,ID> mapSortOrder= new Map<ID,ID>();
        String query='select id, name,(select id, Opportunity_Line_Item_ID__c from QuoteLineItems  ) from Quote where id in :poIds';
        List<id> lstQuotesWithLineItems=Database.query(query);
        for(Quote q: lstQuotesWithLineItems)
        {
            if(q.QuoteLineItems != null)
            {
                for(QuoteLineitem qli : q.QuoteLineItems)
                {
                    if(qli.Opportunity_Line_Item_ID__c!=null)
                    {
                        //map quote line item id with respective opportunity line item id
                         mapSortOrder.put(qli.Id,ID.valueOF(qli.Opportunity_Line_Item_ID__c));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return mapSortOrder;
    }
}
```

Comment: you did a typo. `LineItemlstOppotunityToUpdate` should be instead of `lstOppotunityToUpdate`

Comment: Sorry,It doesn't helped me.

Comment: here `lstOppotunityToUpdate.add(oli);` you are using variable, that is not declared at all.  you declared `LineItemlstOppotunityToUpdate` variable little upper.

Comment: After this It Again shows.Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: LineItemlstOppotunityToUpdate at line 34 column 17

Comment: so what is this `List<id> LineItemlstOppotunityToUpdate = new List<id>();` in your posted code?

Answer (score 1):

this peace of code

```
List<id> LineItemlstOppotunityToUpdate = new List<id>();
for (QuoteLineItem qli : newLineItems) 
{
    OpportunityLineItem oli = mapOppLineItems.get(mapQuoteLineItemSortOrder.get(qli.Id));
    if (oli != null ) 
    {
        oli.Finalization__c=qli.Finalization__c;
        //update more fields...

        lstOppotunityToUpdate.add(oli);
    }
}
update lstOppotunityToUpdate;
```

this line `lstOppotunityToUpdate.add(oli);`.

I don't see variable with this name.  Looks like you want to have `LineItemlstOppotunityToUpdate` instead of `lstOppotunityToUpdate`. you want to update list of sobjects - then store sobjects instead of `Id` in `LineItemlstOppotunityToUpdate`

---

```
List<OpportunityLineItem> LineItemlstOppotunityToUpdate = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
for (QuoteLineItem qli : newLineItems) 
{
    OpportunityLineItem oli = mapOppLineItems.get(mapQuoteLineItemSortOrder.get(qli.Id));
    if (oli != null ) 
    {
        oli.Finalization__c=qli.Finalization__c;
        //update more fields....

        LineItemlstOppotunityToUpdate.add(oli);
    }
}
update LineItemlstOppotunityToUpdate;
```

---

small recommendation to this code. Use `contiansKey` method to check if such key present. Because it is possible to put into `Map` some key and `null` value. And your code `OpportunityLineItem oli = mapOppLineItems.get(mapQuoteLineItemSortOrder.get(qli.Id));` will  be false-negative.

---

```
List<OpportunityLineItem> LineItemlstOppotunityToUpdate = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
for (QuoteLineItem qli : newLineItems) 
{

    if (mapQuoteLineItemSortOrder.containsKey(qli.Id) 
    {
        OpportunityLineItem oli = mapOppLineItems.get(mapQuoteLineItemSortOrder.get(qli.Id));
        oli.Finalization__c=qli.Finalization__c;
        //update more fields....

        LineItemlstOppotunityToUpdate.add(oli);
    }
}
update LineItemlstOppotunityToUpdate;
```

Comment: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(OpportunityLineItem) from the type List<Id> at line 34 column 47

Comment: @Heisenberg I have updated my answer.

Comment: After Updating Your Answer It shows an another Error Illegal assignment from List<SObject> to List<Id> at line 44 column 18